# UWP side loaded app distribution from AAD-protected web site

Tags: azure, uwp, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-authentication

I've got a LOB UWP application which I want to distribute via the web using the [web-based sideloading experience](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/app-installer/installing-windows10-apps-web). This is fairly simple using the VS deployment tools which output an HTML file and the required resources. My goal is to publish the assets to an Azure web app and turn on [Easy Auth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization) so that only people from my org can reach the installer landing page.

This works fine for restricting access to the html page, but the links which point to the actual installer file fail. I'm guessing it's a mime type issue where the auth middleware doesn't know how to handle an Http request with auth information for a non-standard file type:

[image: An error occurred while accessing the file from the web]

I'd appreciate any guidance or suggestions

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft confirmed over on techcommunity.microsoft.com that this is not possible as of yet](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/msix-deployment/uwp-web-distribution-behind-aad-auth/m-p/1624178#M650), but that a solution to support this scenario is on their backlog:

> You're correct - the problem is that App Installer is making its own
> auth request without the inherited web auth tokens. Sending
> authenticated requests is currently not supported today but this is an
> item in our backlog and we're working to address this issue.